# ES6-Importing method from one file to another gives error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, javascript-import

I have an API utils file React JS where i have list of endpoints declared like below-

```
File1.js-
    export const api_endpoints = {
     api1: ()=> '../data/user'
    }
```

I want api1() from File1.js in my another file (File2.js) hence i am importing this like below-

```
import {api_endpoints} from '../File1';
const myObj = {
  [api_endpoints.api1()]: '../data/user2'
}
```

This gives me error in File2 saying-

```
"cannot read property api1 of undefined"
```

I am not sure why api_endpoints comes as undefined in File2.js. The paths are correct. Can someone help me understand that.

Comment: Because `api_endpoints` != `api1_endpoints` (and `file1` != `File1`, but that would be a different error).

Comment: Sorry, corrected. That was a typo while writing. I get the sane error.

Comment: Is the file name and path correct? `File1.js` or `file1.js`

Comment: Is `file` actually one level up in the directory hierarchy? Without context it's essentially impossible to diagnose import/export errors.

Comment: The file name and path is correct.

Comment: You import from `File1` and the error from `File2`, please provide all information.

Comment: Share a reproducible code example showing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are importing from wrong path. Tried the above example and it is working fine for me..

`https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-meninsky-7gbch?file=/src/File2.js`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have just copied it wrong, but you imported {api1_endpoints}, but are asking for api_endpoints